# Verification of integral over $\exp(\cos x + \sin x)$

Tags: integration, special-functions

I found the following integral in a paper I was reading:
\begin{equation}
 \frac{1}{2\pi} \int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi} \exp\left(a \cos x + b \sin x\right) dx = I_0\left(\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\right),
\end{equation}
where $I_0$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind. Unfortunately, there was no reference. I tried to verify the integral with Mathematica, but with no result. I also spend some time to find it in Gradshteyn/Ryzhik, again with no result. Is the above integral correct (including some reference or justification)? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition of the modified Bessel function $I_0$ is
$$
I_0(z)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi e^{z\cos x}dx=\frac{1}{2\,\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{z\cos x}dx
$$
Now
$$
a\cos x+b\sin x=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\cos(x+\phi)
$$
for some angle $\phi$. Since the integral is over a full period, you get the result.

Comment: That turned out to be surprisingly simple. Thank you!