# Integrating the exponential of a periodic function

Tags: definite-integrals, periodic-functions, bessel-functions

I am wondering whether  the following integral

> > $$ Y =  \int_{x_0}^{x_1} \exp{\left(a\cos x+b\sin x\right)}\,dx,$$

has a known closed form for given $a,b,x_0$ and $x_1$.

Since the exponential of the periodic function $a\cos x+b\sin x$ is also periodic, I know that this integral can be computed under a period, and the solution  in terms of a modified Bessel function can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318046/verification-of-integral-over-exp-cos-x-sin-x).

But, what about for general integral limits?

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: [See here](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/9C572E5CE44E9E0DE8630755DF99ABAC/S0013091505000490a.pdf/incomplete-bessel-functions-i.pdf).

Comment: Be more specific, please.

Comment: @A.Pongrácz, I did not get your point.

Comment: @CountIblis, Thanks for the paper. :)